# How to SQL search for related data

Tags: sql

I have created a database containing names and genres of bands.

When someone searches the database for a band, it is meant to return the genre of that band and all other band of the same genre.

So with a layout of:

```
band          | genre
--------------+--------
deep purple   | rock
ac/dc         | rock
adele         | pop
shania twain  | pop
shania twain  | country
black sabbath | rock
```

If I search for "deep purple", I want it to return "rock" but also ac/dc and black sabbath.

I'm having no success with the SQL query.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What SQL query have you tried ?

Comment: You can use 2 query: first find genre, then find all bands by this genre

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    table a
        JOIN table b ON a.genre = b.genre
WHERE   a.band = 'deep purple'
```

This will search the table for the band deep purple, join onto itself using the genre (in this case rock) and return all bands with the genre of rock.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do that. Here's one off the top of my head:

```
select genre, band from MyData where
  genre = 
    (select genre from MyData where
      band = 'deep purple');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM bands
WHERE genre IN (SELECT genre FROM bands WHERE name = 'Deep Purple')
```

Or

```
SELECT b1.* 
FROM bands AS b1
JOIN bands AS b2 ON b1.genre = b2.genre
WHERE b2.name = 'Deep Purple'
```